# owl carousel sliders not working when page is refresh and sometime it works

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

owl carousel sliders works weird.Sometimes initally its not rendering and sometimes it works on refresh and again not rendered when we refresh again.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var owl = $('#sellers');
    var topBooks = $('#schoolBooks');
     owl.owlCarousel({
        nav: true,
        navRewind:true,
        autoplay:true,
        stagePadding:10,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
            },
            414:{
                items: 1.2,
            },
            568:{
                items: 1.5,
            },
            768: {
                items: 2.2
            },
            1024: {
                items: 2.5
            },
            1336:{
                items:3
            },
            1920:{
                itemS:3.5
            }
        }
    });

    topBooks.owlCarousel({
        nav:true,
        loop: true,
        navRewind:true,
        autoWidth:true,
    });
```

How to resolve it.

Comment: Please include HTML too.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*initially is not rendering*"? It takes some time to render or it doesn't render at all and you need to refresh the page for it to render?

Comment: Sometime it renders and when we refresh its not rendering.

Comment: @Pushparaj I am also facing same issue. Did u find solution for that?

Comment: @matheen ulla Owl carousel has some Jquery version issue.Please check the version.and init after it loads

Comment: @Pushparaj thank you for the information. I will check now